# How can I link FLOW3 and TYPO3 4.5?

Tags: typo3-flow

I installed TYPO3 (Blank package, version 4.5.16) in http://local.typo3.in/ and FLOW3 using the terminal command in http://local.flow3.in/.

Then I created a new package using FLOW3. Can I access this package from my TYPO3 website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

TYPO3 before NEOS isn't compatible with FLOW3's packages.

Comment: OK, Can we create a full web site using FLOW3 concept.

Comment: Yes you can, FLOW3 was created for new version of CMS (TYPO3 NEOS), so you can use it as well for custom website, anyway, check its performance first if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

About the performance of TYPO3 Flow, please use PHP 5.4, huge gain compared to 5.3, even in development mode.